# Software to Generate Network Diagrams (Entity Relationships)

Tags: windows, software-rec, networking, diagrams

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for automatically generating and laying out an entity relationship diagram?](https://superuser.com/questions/71709/tool-for-automatically-generating-and-laying-out-an-entity-relationship-diagram)

I am looking for some Windows software that can create relationship diagrams. I am not looking for the fancy kinds like Dia, etc., but rather something simpler where I can type in a bunch of items and specify links between them.

It should then create a picture of the relationships similar to the Google Wonderwheel or Visual Thesaurus. Preferably it will also support some kind of interactive map (like a Flash diagram that lets you pan, zoom, and rotate).

Finally, it would be great if it could support some stats and such like highlighting the most connected entity.

Oh, and it would be great if it could give “degrees of separation” chains between any given two entities.

[image: Visual Thesaurus]

[image: Google Wonderwheel]

Comment: Actually, it is not a duplicate (I DID search already), and certainly NOT an *exact* duplicate. Did you even compare the questions? This question has NOTHING to do with databases.

Comment: In any case, it turns out that GraphVis can do what I wanted with easy to enter data (though it does not—or may not—have the other features I wanted).

Comment: Did read them and compared them as dupes, albeit with a little hook in the database. Had no idea you searched since you never mentioned having looked at the other question at all.